# configure docker-compose logs to omit prepended text

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, kibana

When I run docker-compose up, I get these logs:

```
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-09-09T21:41:46Z","tags":["reporting","browser-driver","warning"],"pid":6,"message":"Enabling the Chromium sandbox provides an additional layer of protection."}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-09-09T21:41:46Z","tags":["reporting","warning"],"pid":6,"message":"Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent pending reports from failing on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in kibana.yml"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-09-09T21:41:46Z","tags":["status","plugin:reporting@7.3.1","info"],"pid":6,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-09-09T21:41:46Z","tags":["info","task_manager"],"pid":6,"message":"Installing .kibana_task_manager index template version: 7030199."}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-09-09T21:41:46Z","tags":["info","task_manager"],"pid":6,"message":"Installed .kibana_task_manager index template: version 7030199 (API version 1)"}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-09-09T21:41:47Z","tags":["info","migrations"],"pid":6,"message":"Creating index .kibana_1."}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-09-09T21:41:47Z","tags":["info","migrations"],"pid":6,"message":"Pointing alias .kibana to .kibana_1."}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-09-09T21:41:47Z","tags":["info","migrations"],"pid":6,"message":"Finished in 254ms."}
kibana_1  | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-09-09T21:41:47Z","tags":["listening","info"],"pid":6,"message":"Server running at http://0:5601"}
```

is there some configuration I can use so that it only spits out JSON? I am looking for it to omit the `"kibana_1  | "` part before each line.

And of course, ideally it could make that part of the JSON, like `{"source":"kibana_1", ...}`

Answer (score 0):

Note: Not sure if docker-compose supports this out of the box but you can look at Docker logging drivers.

---

What you could do is use the `cut` command piping output from `docker-compose logs -f`.

Here is an example below:

```
docker-compose logs -f kibana | cut -d"|" -f2
```

```
..
 {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-08-11T03:44:01Z","tags":["status","plugin:xpack_main@6.8.1","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from red to green - Ready","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Request Timeout after 3000ms"}
 {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-08-11T03:44:01Z","tags":["status","plugin:graph@6.8.1","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from red to green - Ready","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Request Timeout after 3000ms"}
 {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-08-11T03:44:01Z","tags":["status","plugin:searchprofiler@6.8.1","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from red to green - Ready","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Request Timeout after 3000ms"}
..
```

The `cut -d"|" -f2` command will look for a `|` character and output everything after.

You can take it a step further (although i'm sure there are better ways to do this) by deleting the leading space.

```
docker-compose logs -f kibana | cut -d"|" -f2 | cut -d" " -f2
```

```
..
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-08-11T03:47:53Z","tags":["status","plugin:maps@6.8.1","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-08-11T03:47:53Z","tags":["status","plugin:index_management@6.8.1","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2019-08-11T03:47:53Z","tags":["status","plugin:index_lifecycle_management@6.8.1","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status
..
```

Comment: Missed your note about adding `{"source":"kibana_1", ...}`. Don't have time to test it right now, but you can start off with `sed -e 's/kibana\s*|//'` which will replace the first set of characteres. You should then figure out the regex to get "{" and replace it adding the `{"source":"kibana_1", ...}` part.